# Django Test unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I can't import my models in my tests directory, this is my error :

```
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.test_views (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_views
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\wamp\www\km0\tests\test_views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import Entreprise
  File "c:\wamp\www\km0\tests\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Entreprise(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.5-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\ba
se.py", line 102, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class tests.models.Entreprise doesn't declare an explicit ap
p_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
Preserving test database for alias 'default' ('test_km0')...
```

I did some research and couldn't find an answer ...

test_views.py :

```
from django.test import TestCase
import unittest
from .models import Entreprise

class Km0ViewsTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_cart(self):
        resp = self.client.get('/fr/cart/')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        resp = self.client.get('/en/cart/')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        resp = self.client.get('/de/cart/')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

My directory :
[my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf78d.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: As the error suggests, try adding the app which contains the model (`km0`?) to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: @Alasdair I did :
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'geoposition',
    'front',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap3',
    'km0',
)

But doesn't work :/

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, the model is in `km0.tests.models`, not `km0.models` as I assumed. What is the model for, and why have you defined your model there? Do you only use it for the tests?

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, I put a copy models of km0 in tests directory because I followed a tutorial and they explain that you need a models file in tests directory. If I remove this models file of tests directory, how I can access front directory which contains the true models file from my test_views.py ? (Thanks for your help)

Comment: You shouldn't normally need a `models.py` in your tests directory. If you want to import `Entreprise` from `km0/models.py`, then change the import to `from km0.models import Entreprise` or  `from ..models import Entreprise`.

Comment: @Alasdair THANKS A LOT ! I did : from front.models import Entreprise and it worked pretty well ! (my models file was in front directory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't normally need a `models.py` in your tests directory.

If you want to import your `Entreprise` model from the `front` app, then change your import from

```
from .models import Entreprise
```

to

```
from front.models import Entreprise
```

Comment: Thank you for your big help ! I can't upvote your answer since I am new here and need 15 pts for upvoting a post. But well I marked your answer as accepted ! :)